# What's the difference between &<< and << operators in Swift?

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation, operators, bit

What's the difference between &<< and << operators in Swift? It seems like they return the same results:

```
print(2 << 3) // 16
print(2 &<< 3) // 16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`FixedWithInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger) protocol defines the “masking left shift operator” [`&<<`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2964298) as

> Returns the result of shifting a value’s binary representation the
>   specified number of digits to the left, masking the shift amount to
>   the type’s bit width.
>
> Use the masking left shift operator (`&<<`) when you need to perform a
>   shift and are sure that the shift amount is in the range
>   `0..<lhs.bitWidth`. Before shifting, the masking left shift operator
>   masks the shift to this range. The shift is performed using this
>   masked value.

So the results can differ if the shift amount is larger than or equal to the bit width of the left operand: Example:

```
print(2 << 70) // 0
print(2 &<< 70) // 128
```

Here the shift amount (70) is larger than the bitwith of `Int` (64), so that `2 << 70` evaluates to zero.
In the second line, the number is shifted to the left by 70 % 64 = 6 bits.

There is also a similar “masking right shift operator” `&>>`. Example:

```
let x = Int8.min        // -128 = 0b10000000
print(Int8.min >> 8)    //   -1 = 0b11111111
print(Int8.min &>> 8)   // -128 = 0b10000000
```

Here the first result is `-1` because shifting a *signed* integer to the right fills empty positions on the left with the *sign bit.* The second result is `-128` because the shift amount is zero: `8 % 8 = 0`.

Naming and intended usage is also described in [SR-6749](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6749):

> The goal of the operator, however, is never to have this wrapping
>   behavior happen — it's what you use when you have static knowledge
>   that your shift amount is <= the bitWidth. By masking, you and the
>   compiler can agree that there's no branch needed, so you get slightly
>   faster code without zero branching and zero risk of undefined behavior
>   (which a negative or too large shift would be).
>
> The docs are confusing because they give an example I don't think
>   anyone would ever intentionally write—relying on the wrapping behavior
>   to use some out of bounds value for the shift amount.

So using masked shift operators can increase the performance. Many examples can be found in the source code of the Swift standard library, for example in [UTF8.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/UTF8.swift).

Comment: I would add that in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html all operators prefixed with `&` handle overflow correctly.

Comment: @tk421: It is similar, but not completely: `2 << 70` is well-defined in Swift and does not cause an overflow at runtime.